# How to add a Favorite - UnFavorite Button with vue.js 2?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.3, vuejs2

My view is like this :

```
<div class="panel panel-default panel-store-info">
    ...
    <div class="favorite"> 
        <add-favorite-store :id-store="{{ $store->id }}"></add-favorite-store>
    </div>
    ....
</div>
```

My component is like this :

```
<template>
    <a href="javascript:" class="btn btn-block btn-success" @click="addFavoriteStore($event)">
        <span class="fa fa-heart"></span>&nbsp;Favorite
    </a>
</template>

<script>
    export default{
        props:['idStore'],
        methods:{
            addFavoriteStore(event){
                event.target.disabled = true
                const payload= {id_store: this.idStore}
                this.$store.dispatch('addFavoriteStore', payload)
                setTimeout(function () {
                    location.reload(true)
                }, 1500);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

When click button favorite, it will call controller on the laravel

The action, I using vuex store

When click the button favorites, I want to change it to be unfavorite button. Vice versa.

I've been looking for references. But I have not found it. I was new in vue.js

So I requested your help.

Is there anyone can help me?

Comment: I think you can refer a favoriting feature below 
https://scotch.io/tutorials/implement-a-favoriting-feature-using-laravel-and-vue-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just looking for text change in button, you can save the text on button in a variable and change that variable when clicking the button, like following:

```
<template>
    <a href="javascript:" class="btn btn-block btn-success" @click="addFavoriteStore($event)">
        <span class="fa fa-heart"></span>&nbsp;{{idStore ? 'Unfavorite' : 'Favorite'}}
    </a>
</template>

<script>
    export default{
        props:['idStore'],
        data () {
        }
        methods:{
            addFavoriteStore(event){
                event.target.disabled = true
                const payload= {id_store: this.idStore}
                this.$store.dispatch('addFavoriteStore', payload)
                setTimeout(function () {
                    location.reload(true)
                }, 1500);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: When I click favorite button, it does not turn into un-favorite button. I check in console also no error. So it's not working

Comment: @mosestoh I have moved that line up so that it should reflect.

Comment: It works. But after calling the action and refresh the page, it's back to the favorite button

Comment: Yes because when you will refresh to will reset this data, Do you have some other variable based on which you can decide what text to show?